# Running .NET 1.1 Application on .NET 3.5

Tags: .net

I am having Windows application using remoting, developed in .NET 1.1. Now I want to upgrade the application to .NET 3.5. The way I supposed to do this is by converting the code of 1.1 to 3.5 using Visual Studio 2008 and then compile that code using VS 2008 and deploy the application on .NET 3.5 framework. The questions I am having related to this are:

1. Is there any benefit of conervting the .NET 1.1 application to .NET 3.5
2. Is there any benefit in performance of application
3. Is it going to benefit me, as Microsoft has stopped support for .NET 1.1

Any other benefits?
What are the issues going to face in this activity?

Comment: If you are intending on maintaining or even enhancing the App, then I would recommend conversion to 3.5. The newer the tech, the more time-savers it's got.

Answer (score 1):

If the application is no longer under development then there won't be a ton of benefits to migrating the code for the application.  I do believe there are some performance improvements om the 2.0 runtime, but I don't think you will get much advantage out of them if you don't change your code.   If the app is still under development that changes from 1.1 to 3.5 are massive and make you life a lot easier as a developer. Also why 3.5 now that 4.0 is out and with it a entire new runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll see any performance benefit.

Converting to 3.5 means you don't need to have the 1.1 runtime on your target machine(s). As you noted, 1.1 is unsupported.